# Is it Risky (and how much) to allow full control to the system folder?

Tags: windows

How much risk is there to allow full control to an administrator to the system folder? 
What i actually need is to edit host File in System32 Folder for that i need to allow full control to an administrator to the system folder?

This message says that this can reduce system security:

[image: System Message]

Comment: On the file in the screenshot, none.

Comment: Question updated !

Comment: My comment remains the same.  There are no side effects from modifying the hosts file.  So the only file you should be giving yourself full control over, is the hosts file, if your changing the permissions on entire directories you will cause system instability.

Answer (score 0):

Addressing your screenshot, it's totally normal for the Admin group to have full control

In practice, Admins are the only users who are meant to be assigned to the "Administrator" group, they are usually people the company trust and pay well in order to keep everything working.

Assigning only trusted people i.e System administrators or some trusted Developers to this group is totally normal and safe.

If every average joe in the company is in this group then it can cause big problems, if this is the case, the i'd recommend changing it immediately, otherwise your servers / network could be infected with malware from some user downloading files form the wrong website.

I'd recommend watching some of these videos to get a better understanding of users, groups, and permissions

**Creating and Administering Groups in Active Directory on Windows Server 2012**
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=C3UV3RTW7HI

**Introduction to File and Share Permissions in Windows Server 2012**
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=fJHFmt6F0Rc

**Creating and Administering User Accounts in Active Directory on Windows Server 2012**
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=DrNwJraGfjQ

Comment: acctually i was just trying to edit `host` file To edit that host file  i need to allow an administrator or user  full control

Answer (score 0):

To address your issue specifically of the `hosts` file... all you need to do is run Notepad elevated and then use File->Open to edit it.  You can't just double-click on it from an Explorer window.  That file in particular is locked down.

Aside from that, the default permissions on the `\Windows` and `\Program Files` directories are actually quite specific and there is some ACL trickery applied that is very difficult to restore should you go changing permissions.  You an see this on the Advanced settings; lots of special permissions scoped to different levels.  **You shouldn't ever change the permissions on the operating system directories or the root of the C: drive.**  Doing so will cause some serious problems that you will only be able to revert by dropping a Full Conttrol somewhere that will actually make the security situation worse than what it was to begin with.

If UAC is on (which you really shouldn't turn it off without a specific reason), Windows provides additional protections for the `\Windows` and `\Program Files` directories so that even Administrators cannot write files there without explicitly elevating their credentials.

If you find that the security on the system is too permissive, you should address the users' access privileges rather than trying to modify the directory permissions.